# Write a program that takes in a line of text as input, and outputs that line of text in reverse. C++

Tags: c++

Write a program that takes in a line of text as input, and outputs that line of text in reverse. The program repeats, ending when the user enters "Quit", "quit", or "q" for the line of text.

Ex: If the input is:
Hello
there
Hey
quit

Then the output is:
ereht
olleH
yeH

I tried this, but for some reason, it is giving me a new line in when a print the code and I do not know how to fix it, please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
     string userInput;
       while (true)
       {
       string check = userInput;
       if (check =="quit" || check == "Quit" || check =="q") {
           break;
       }

    string reverse = "";
    for (int i = userInput.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reverse = reverse + userInput.at(i);
    }

    cout << reverse << endl;
    cin >> userInput;
}


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Provide some [mre] in your question.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: The requirement does not match the example.

Comment: Note: If you just need to print the output, don't make the reverse string. Just print the characters out instead of putting them in `reverse`

Comment: Think carefully about the order in which things should happen. If you want to read the `userInput` from the user, and also check whether `userInput` is equal to whichever test strings, what should happen first: the reading, or the checking? Now, which *does* happen first in your program? Do you understand why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input statement

```
cin >> userInput;
```

happens only at the end of your `main`. Try moving it at the start of your `main`.

Read [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) website. Consider reading the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf).

Read first [*some good C++ programming book*](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html), the documentation of your C++ compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), invoked as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`), and the documentation of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)).

### Take inspiration from existing open source C++ software

such as [Qt](https://qt.io/), [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/), [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) (which should be helpful), [Fish](https://fishshell.com/), [FLTK](https://fltk.org/) etc.... and many others on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/).

Read more about [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) and [`std::cin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin)